# make appear rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanna make appear another row when id_edad_quinq doesnt exists

for example id_edad_quinq='11' and genero='1' doesnt exist and put "0" in total column
this is my script

Here I create a temporal table

```
SELECT ID_CITA,
       FECHA_ATENCION,
       (case 
            when Tipo_Edad IN('M','D') THEN 1
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 1 AND 4 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 2
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 5 AND 9 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 3
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 10 AND 14 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 4
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 15 AND 19 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 5
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 20 AND 24 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 6
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 25 AND 29 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 7
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 30 AND 34 AND Tipo_Edad='A' THEN 8
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 35 AND 39 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 9
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 40 AND 44 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 10
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 45 AND 49 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 11
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 50 AND 54 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 12
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 55 AND 59 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 13
            when  Edad_Reg BETWEEN 60 AND 64 AND Tipo_Edad='A'  THEN 14
            when  Edad_Reg >=65 AND TIPO_EDAD='A' THEN 15
            ELSE 0
      END) AS ID_EDAD_QUINQ,
      (CASE WHEN TC.GENERO ='F' THEN 2 
            WHEN TC.Genero ='M' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
      END) AS GENERO,
      Descripcion_Item,
      Codigo_Item
INTO #casos_morbilidad
FROM BDHIS_MINSA.dbo.T_CONSOLIDADO_NUEVA_TRAMA_HISMINSA tc
WHERE Descripcion_Red like '%viru%' and mes=1 and concat(id_cita,'-',Id_Correlativo_Item) 
     IN (SELECT concat(id_cita,'-',Id_Correlativo_Item) 
     from BDHIS_MINSA.dbo.T_CONSOLIDADO_NUEVA_TRAMA_HISMINSA TC 
     WHERE LEFT(Codigo_Item,1) NOT IN ('Z','U'))
AND Tipo_Diagnostico='D'
AND Fg_Tipo='CX'
```

here show the results for the second image

```
select genero,id_edad_quinq, codigo_item, count(id_cita) as total
from #casos_morbilidad
group by genero, id_edad_quinq, codigo_item
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste images of code or data, please paste in as text. Please show sample data and expected results.

Comment: You can't just magically have a query return rows that don't exist. You probably need to use a tally or numbers table as your main query here with a left join to your data. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1